# How to remove low priority task python queue

Tags: python, queue

```
import Queue as queue

prio_queue = queue.PriorityQueue()
prio_queue.put((1, "Hello Brother"))
prio_queue.put((3, 'Nothing at all'))
prio_queue.put((2, 'Hello Teacher'))

while not prio_queue.empty():
    item = prio_queue.get()
    print ('%s %s' % item)
```

I have these three tasks and running them with python queue library, just to remove lowest priority task i.e. 3

Comment: If the lowest priority is the one with the lowest value (i. e. 1 in your case), then the `get()` will do it.  Otherwise (if you mean the 3 is the lowest priority) this class has no interface to do what you want.

Comment: You can always simply negate the priorities when you insert into the queue i.e. prior_queue.put((-1,"Hello Brother")), then 3 becomes -3 and  the lowest value (i.e. head of) in the queue

Comment: How to print the name of each task in the queue in reverse priority order? without negating the original priority?